# Rendering data from mob-x store

Tags: reactjs, mobx

I am trying to make my h1 tag that contains the Offers: text display 0 from my mob-x store, because 
the auto array is empty, but the h1 tag does not display anything, the whole app
compiles with only one error:

Warning: Failed prop type: Invalid prop `Auto` of type `array` supplied to `inject-CardCheck-with-Auto`, expected `string`.
    in inject-CardCheck-with-Auto (created by Auto)

I changed it to string but it still doesn't work

Why does the h1 tag not render 0 and how can I make it work?

I have this React component:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { inject, observer } from 'mobx-react';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';
import './cardCheck.css';

@inject('Auto')
@observer
class CardCheck extends Component {
  render() {
    const { Auto } = this.props;

    return (
      <div>
        <div className="newsletter-container">
          <h1>Enter the ID of your card:</h1>
          <div className="center">
            <input type="number" />
            <input type="submit" value="Check" />
          </div>
        </div>
        <h1>Offers:{Auto.carCount}</h1>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

CardCheck.propTypes = {
  Auto: PropTypes.string
};

CardCheck.defaultProps = {
  Auto: []
};

export default CardCheck
```

and this is my mobx store:

```
import { observable, action, computed } from 'mobx';

class Auto {
  @observable auto = [];

  @action
  addAuto(car) {
    this.auto.push(car);
  }

  @computed
  get carCount() {
    return this.auto.length;
  }
}

export { Auto };
```

and here is my Provider:

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import { Provider } from 'mobx-react';
import { Restaurants } from './stores/Restaurants';
import { Beauty } from './stores/Beauty';
import { Tech } from './stores/Tech';
import { Malls } from './stores/ClothesData';
import App from './App';
import { Auto } from './stores/Auto';

const restaurants = new Restaurants();
const beauty = new Beauty();
const tech = new Tech();
const mall = new Malls();
const auto = new Auto();

window.restaurants = restaurants;
window.beauty = beauty;
window.tech = tech;
window.mall = mall;
window.auto = auto;

ReactDOM.render(
  <Provider restaurants={restaurants} beauty={beauty} tech={tech} mall={mall} auto={auto}>
    <App />
  </Provider>,
  document.querySelector('.container')
);
```

Comment: You are giving the `auto` store to the `Provider` as `auto`, but you try to use the `Auto` prop, with a capital `A`. Write `const { auto } = this.props;` and `@inject('auto')` instead.

Comment: I made the changes but it still dosen't work

Comment: Is `auto` still `undefined` if you `console.log` it in the render method of `CardCheck`?

Comment: yes it gives this error: checkPropTypes.js:19 Warning: Failed prop type: Invalid prop `auto` of type `array` supplied to `inject-CardCheck-with-auto`, expected `string`.
    in inject-CardCheck-with-auto (created by Auto)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are 3 mistakes in your codes.

1. Your `propTypes` conflicts with your `defaultProps`. You specified `Auto` to be a **string**, while you set it to be an empty **array** by default. That is the reason of  the error message you see.
2. As mentioned above, you need to change all `Auto` into `auto` in your CardCheck class.
3. Actually, your store is neither a string nor an array, it is an **object** that contains an array.

After fixing all errors, the class should look like this in my opinion.

```
@inject('auto')
@observer
class CardCheck extends Component {
  render() {
    const { auto } = this.props;

    return (
      <div>
        // ...
        <h1>Offers:{auto.carCount}</h1>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

CardCheck.propTypes = {
  auto: PropTypes.shape({
    carCount: PropTypes.number,
    // if needed, use PropTypes.observableArray of MobX to check auto.auto here
  }),
};

CardCheck.defaultProps = {
  auto: {
    carCount: 0,
  }
};

export default CardCheck;
```